# Reference request: existence, uniqueness, and regularity of solutions to elliptic PDEs with periodic boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, boundary-value-problem, regularity-theory-of-pdes, linear-pde

I am interested in Theorems regarding existence, uniqueness, and regularity of solutions to linear 2nd order elliptic PDEs with periodic boundary conditions, e.g.,
$$\begin{cases} -u''+u=f & 0<x<1\\ u(0)=u(1) & \\ u'(0)=u'(1)\end{cases}$$
where $f\in L^2(0,1)$. The literature I can find is focused on numerical methods for such problems or analysis for much more complicated problems with periodic BCs. Is there a foundational paper or textbook that discusses this type of problem as Evans does for Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice treatment of Sobolev spaces and boundary value problems in one dimension can be found in Chapter 8 of the text:

*Brezis, Haim*, [**Functional analysis, Sobolev spaces and partial differential equations**](https://mathoverflow.net/a/397937), Universitext. New York, NY: Springer (ISBN 978-0-387-70913-0/pbk; 978-0-387-70914-7/ebook). xiii, 599 p. (2011). [ZBL1220.46002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1220.46002).

In particular Section 8.4 discusses boundary value problems, and Example 7 in said particular treats the exact problem you mention. The techniques developed in said text should also allow you to establish the well-posedness theory of similar equations.